# To connect a shower valve to PVC tube

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have a house where the pipes are all PVC. I have one tube running to my shower head and I need to connect it to the valve. All the valves I see online have 3 connectors. I only need one and it will be being connected to a single piece of PVC tubing. What do I need to look for when I am purchasing a new valve and handle?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Any shower valve will have three connections (two in, one out), and adapting PVC to NPT or whatever shouldn't be terribly difficult. You probably won't find a valve _designed_ for PVC.

Comment: No it’s only in. Just one single tube no extras. One to the valve and one to shower. But the pvc is already concreted into the wall

Comment: If there isn't a hot supply and a cold supply, only an "out to shower head" then no shower valve in the world will work. As for "concreted into the wall" that's a needless complication that may have to be solved with a masonry chisel, but perhaps a union would work. But it won't matter without a hot and cold supply to the valve.

Comment: I’m using an external water heater that hangs on the wall

Comment: It sounds like you only need a simple on/off valve instead of a shower(or any hot/cold) mixing valve.  A bit chancely to depend on a heater itself not to boil you.

Comment: I’m in Costa Rica. Where showers are always an electrocution risk :) or boiling to death risk

Answer (score 1):

Is this one of the shower units with its own water heater, as found in the UK and other places where whole-house hot water may not be available? If so, you need an appropriate pipe or hose to connect this cut-off valve to the shower's input.

This valve appears to use hose thread. The shower's input may use hose thread (as would a washing machine) or pipe thread. If it's hose thread, you just buy a short hookup hose such as those used for washing machines, attach both ends, and you're done. If the shower connection is pipe thread, you would need an adapter, probably available the same place you buy that hose. If you add a photo of the shower's connection, we may be able to give you more specific advice.